# Is it possible for two securities to have the same first 8 characters of a cusip, but differ in the check sum?

Tags: fixed-income, finance, banking-regulations

CUSIP is a 9 character long identifier. The last digit is a check sum checking the first 8 previous characters. This seems to me that it is not possible for two securities to have the same 8 characters and different check sum. I know this is not exactly quantitative, but I haven't found a forum where I could ask.

Source: https://www.cusip.com/cusip/index.htm

Comment: No, for exactly the reasons you state, two CUSIPs *cannot* differ in inly the last digit. The last digit is a function of the first 8 digits, and any ordered set of 8 digits has only one proper checksum. If two CUSIPs are the same except for rhe last digit, one of them is not a CUSIP, and in fact ***making that determination is the very purpose of the checksum digit***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 9th character is computed using deterministic algorithm described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP#Check_digit_pseudocode.